# expanding dates outside of current range

Tags: time, stata

I am trying to expand a data set to include dates outside of the current range.

The data I have ranges from 1992q1 to 2017q1. Each observation exists within a portion of that larger window, for example from 1993q2 to 1997q1.

I need to create quarterly observations for each range to fill the missing time. I have already expanded the existing data into quarters.

What I cannot figure out how to do is add in those missing quarters. For example, country1 may have the dates 1993q2 to 1997q1. I need to add in the missing dates from 1992q1 to 1993q1 and 1997q2 to 2017q1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple analogue of I want I think is your question is shown by this sandbox dataset.

```
clear 
set obs 10 
gen id = cond(_n < 7, 1, 2) 
gen qdate = yq(1992, 1) in 1 
replace qdate = yq(1992, 3) in 7 
bysort id (qdate) : replace qdate = qdate[_n-1] + 1 if missing(qdate) 
format qdate %tq 
list, sepby(id) 

     +-------------+
     | id    qdate |
     |-------------|
  1. |  1   1992q1 |
  2. |  1   1992q2 |
  3. |  1   1992q3 |
  4. |  1   1992q4 |
  5. |  1   1993q1 |
  6. |  1   1993q2 |
     |-------------|
  7. |  2   1992q3 |
  8. |  2   1992q4 |
  9. |  2   1993q1 |
 10. |  2   1993q2 |
     +-------------+

fillin id qdate 
list, sepby(id) 

     +-----------------------+
     | id    qdate   _fillin |
     |-----------------------|
  1. |  1   1992q1         0 |
  2. |  1   1992q2         0 |
  3. |  1   1992q3         0 |
  4. |  1   1992q4         0 |
  5. |  1   1993q1         0 |
  6. |  1   1993q2         0 |
     |-----------------------|
  7. |  2   1992q1         1 |
  8. |  2   1992q2         1 |
  9. |  2   1992q3         0 |
 10. |  2   1992q4         0 |
 11. |  2   1993q1         0 |
 12. |  2   1993q2         0 |
     +-----------------------+
```

So. `fillin` is a simple way of ensuring that all cross-combinations of identifier and time are present. However, to what benefit? Although not shown in this example, values of other variables spring into existence only as missing values. In some situations, proceeding with interpolation is justified, but usually, you just live with incomplete panels.

How to find solutions like these? One good strategy is to skim through the [D] manual to see what basic data management commands exist.